# If I don't need no specify a type in generic class should I use <?>

Tags: java, generics

I have a class for manage messages. The message is an object so I have created a generic class for that task

```
public class Message<T> {
    String code;
    T data;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Sometimes, I only need to use the message for carrying "code" without a specific "data" . In this case what is the best practice? Should I use unbound wildcard for this need?

```
public void test(){
    Message<?> message = new Message<>();
    message.setCode("HELLO_WORLD"); 
}
```

I understand that this way, the compiler assigns Object type to field data. Is this a good practice?  I think is readable for programmer because it specifies that the type is not important to define. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think you yan use it like that. Or you can define the type string to add a description to your code

Comment: You should use `Object`. If you use `<?>` you will get a different escaped-type every time you refer to it.

Comment: @user207421 what do you mean when saying " you will get a different escaped-type every time you refer to it"? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

I think using the question mark  can be considered "okay".

But a more " typed" way would be to use different classes here.

Like: a base class Message that only has that `code` property. And a derived class PayloadMessage that adds that `data` element.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example please? I understand that you recommend to use a Base class Message and inherit it from PayloadMessage? or am I wrong?

Comment: @OctavioCega Message has only "code". PayloadMessage extends Message, and adds data. That is really straight forward OOP and inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store "stuff", use `Object` as the type.

```
public void test(){
    Message<Object> message = new Message<>();
    message.setCode("HELLO_WORLD"); 
}
```

it handles all cases, and you will never get into a tangle of generics like you can with `?` as the type.

Comment: What could be a problem with using the unbounded wildcard <?> ? Is there any reason to prefer the Object type when the Type of the generic class is not important?

Comment: Why not Void then for example. Using generics with Object is something that have seen like ... never methinks. Very surprising to the reader.